# Which video formats for universal viewing ? (across browsers, tablettes and smartphones etc) and standard size

Tags: video

Need a quick help from those who are making user submitted video sites. I used uploadify to upload a mp4 video (directly from my handycam) and found that the format was visible neither in my Firefox (XP) nor in my Samsung Galaxy.

So the question is, in which format or formats I should convert the videos for universal viewing across all platforms. Any suggestion here ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following, thought to post it in case it helps someone : http://www.videojs.com/